# Taylor series for $\ln \left( 1 + e^{b_0 + b_1x} \right)$ centered at $x = a$ such that $a \neq 0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am working with $\ln \left( 1 + e^{b_0 + b_1x} \right)$ centered at $x = a$ such that $a \neq 0$ where $b_0$ and $b_1$ are fixed. My background is in statistics and I have some knowledge about these but not very deep. My questions are:

1. **Convergence:** Is the Taylor series for this function convergent? That is, does it converge to the function as we include more terms in the series (if I understood the meaning of 'convergence' correctly)?

   a. If yes, is it still only for $\left|e^{b_0 + b_1x}\right| < 1$, like for the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$, or it can be on another interval since I am considering $a \neq 0$? Which interval is it then?

   b. If not, does it still make sense to use Taylor polynomials up to a certain order to approximate this function?
2. **Error:**

   a. Is there a general expression for the Taylor series/polynomial of $k$th order for this function? What is it?

   b. How do we find the error bound for this function?
3. **Sum of Taylor series:**

   a. Given the Taylor series expansion of the function centered at $a \neq 0$ evaluated at $x_i$ such that $i=1,...,n$: Is it ok to add up the corresponding Taylor series/polynomials?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.